# Trying to make a function hide and reveal 2 images

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code. I'm trying to hide another image behind another and make a button press switch which image is visible along with changing the href link.

```js
function revealHQ() {
  var pilaf = document.getElementById('PilafHQ');
  var altaf = document.getElementById('altafsung');
  // get the current value of the hidden image's display property
  var displaySetting = altaf.style.display;
  // now toggle the clock and the button text, depending on current state
  if (displaySetting == 'block') {
    // hidden message is visible. hide it
    altaf.style.display = 'none';
    pilaf.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    // if message is hidden. show it
    altaf.style.display = 'block';
    pilaf.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
.altafsung {
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  perspective: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  display: block;
}

.PilafHQ {
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  perspective: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://tse1.mm.bing.net/th/id/OIP.9uW8U7EhqDOzl1-gONQjwAHaGj?pid=ImgDet&rs=1" target="_blank">
  <div class="PilafHQ"><img src="Images/Pilaf Castle Entrance cropped.png " alt="Pilaf castle entrance" width="250" height="250"></div>
</a>
<a href="https://altafs-bazaar.bertry.repl.co/" target="_blank">
  <div class="altafsung"><img src="Images/Altaf Bazaar Advert.png" alt="Altaf Sunglasses" width="250" height="250"></div>
</a>
<img src="Images/walkingbear.gif" alt="polar bear walking " onclick="revealHQ();">
```

Comment: And what exacly is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Thanks you for sharing your code.  Did you have a specific problem?

Comment: the code doesn't function

Comment: This is essentially a typo.  The browser's console is telling you the problem.  `getElementById('PilafHQ')` - There is no such element.  Your elements are using `class`, not `id`.  Switch them to use an `id` and you can find them by their `id`.

Comment: I made a snippet. The console message is clear

Comment: A better way is to use classList.toggle() on both elements

Answer (score 0):

Use ID on the elements when you want to access byId

It is simpler to toggle the class

I gave the emoji an ID too

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // when page loads
  document.getElementById("toggleImage").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var pilaf = document.getElementById('PilafHQ');
    var altaf = document.getElementById('altafsung');
    // show one, hide the other
    altaf.classList.toggle("hide")
    pilaf.classList.toggle("hide")
  });
});
```

```css
.altafsung {
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  perspective: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
}

.PilafHQ {
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  perspective: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
}

.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<a href="https://tse1.mm.bing.net/th/id/OIP.9uW8U7EhqDOzl1-gONQjwAHaGj?pid=ImgDet&rs=1" target="_blank">
  <div id="PilafHQ" class="hide"><img src="Images/Pilaf Castle Entrance cropped.png " alt="Pilaf castle entrance" width="250" height="250"></div>
</a>
<a href="https://altafs-bazaar.bertry.repl.co/" target="_blank">
  <div id="altafsung"><img src="Images/Altaf Bazaar Advert.png" alt="Altaf Sunglasses" width="250" height="250"></div>
</a>
<img id="toggleImage" src="Images/walkingbear.gif" alt="polar bear walking ">
```